# Applescript for saving files in pptx format

Tags: applescript, powerpoint

how do I save a powerpoint presentation in pptx format in Office 2016 for Mac?   the script "save active presentation as save as presentation" only gets me ppt files (old format)

Answer (score 0):

It's

```
save active presentation as presentation
```

without `as save`